# The Target Of The Callback Could Not Be Found

Tags: internet, popups

I have been getting this popup message for a while now and was wondering if someone had some insight into why this is happening. When browsing to a Microsoft website a popup appears stating: The target of the callback could not be found. Why is this happening?

I went to this [site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS) today and found the problem.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Internet Explorer:

[image: IE]

Comment: What browser? What operating system? Anything special about your JavaScript configuration? HTTP proxy we should know about?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I am running Windows 7 Professional. This popup happens on both Chome 17.0.963.79 and Internet Explorer 9. When you go to the link do you see this popup message? I have recently installed a fresh OS and remember I had the same issue on the previous installation.

Comment: No, I don't get the popup here. I also took a quick peak into some of the `.js` files to see if the string would be in one of them, but it wasn't in the ones I checked. The error message is just too generic to pin it to something specific. It just seems like you're not alone with this issue from what I read on Google.

Comment: This been bugging me for month, but apparently it's not known as an issue at Microsoft - at least I could not find any information that would indicate so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a JavaScript message about a failed attempt to execute some code (the "callback"). Coders put messages like these in their site to help them diagnose problems while they build them. When you publish the site, it's considered best practice to turn these debugging messages off so that visitors don't see them. Clearly, this hasn't happened.

Generally speaking, this site uses some sloppy and complex JavaScript code, and it's unsurprising that there are some user-facing bugs. Oliver, the .js string might be in a nested lib somewhere... there's a ton of code here (over 20 external js includes, and some repeats).

If you want, you can poke around in IE settings and try to turn off JavaScript warnings, but I would otherwise ignore this message. It's just an awkwardly made website.